# How to load XML document from `std::istream`?

Tags: c++, std, tinyxml

I'd like to load TinyXml documents from `std::istream`, but it doesn't contain such method:

```
/** Load a file using the current document value.
    Returns true if successful. Will delete any existing
    document data before loading.
*/
bool LoadFile( TiXmlEncoding encoding = TIXML_DEFAULT_ENCODING );
/// Save a file using the current document value. Returns true if successful.
bool SaveFile() const;
/// Load a file using the given filename. Returns true if successful.
bool LoadFile( const char * filename, TiXmlEncoding encoding = TIXML_DEFAULT_ENCODING );
/// Save a file using the given filename. Returns true if successful.
bool SaveFile( const char * filename ) const;
/** Load a file using the given FILE*. Returns true if successful. Note that this method
    doesn't stream - the entire object pointed at by the FILE*
    will be interpreted as an XML file. TinyXML doesn't stream in XML from the current
    file location. Streaming may be added in the future.
*/
bool LoadFile( FILE*, TiXmlEncoding encoding = TIXML_DEFAULT_ENCODING );
```

I see that it contains function that uses `FILE`, is it possible to convert `std::istream` to `FILE`?

Comment: No, at least not in any standard way. It is possible to convert a FILE to an istream however, is that good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found clear solution [here](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/index.html):

> C++ style input:
>
> - based on std::istream
> - operator>>
>
> Reads XML from a stream, making it useful for network transmission.
>   The tricky part is knowing when the XML document is complete, since
>   there will almost certainly be other data in the stream. TinyXML will
>   assume the XML data is complete after it reads the root element. Put
>   another way, documents that are ill-constructed with more than one
>   root element will not read correctly. Also note that operator>> is
>   somewhat slower than Parse, due to both implementation of the STL and
>   limitations of TinyXML.

Example:

```
std::istream *in = ResourceManager::getInstance().getResource(resourceName);
if(in) {
   TiXmlDocument doc;
   // load document from resource stream
   *in >> doc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Load the entire data from the `istream` and then use [`TiXmlDocument::Parse`](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlDocument.html#17ebabe36926ef398e78dec0d0ad0378).

Comment: Good idea, but I've found better solution after some time spent googling. :)