# How to pass argument to Google test point during runtime?

Tags: c++, googletest

Is there a way to pass arguments to google test points during run time?
I know I can static arguments using

```
TEST_P(fooTest,testPointName)
{
}
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(InstantiationName,
                        FooTest,
                        ::testing::Values("blah"));
```

But in my use case I want to do something like

```
main(){
//do Something
//create instance of ::testing::Values type
//pass arguments to  multiple test points
//run_tests
}
```

I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Were any of the answers helpful? Please provide some feedback.

Comment: Similar problem to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286104/data-driven-unit-tests-with-google-test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using `SetUpTestCase`. In you fixture class, create a static variable that will hold your desired values. Then implement a static functions `SetUpTestCase` and `TearDownTestCase` in your fixture class that will initialize and cleanup your values. Here is the general idea:

```
class MyFixture : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
    static void SetUpTestCase() {
        // Code that sets up m_values for testing
    }

    static void TearDownTestCase() {
        // Code that cleans up m_values. This function can be ommited if
        // there are no specific clean up tasks necessary.
    }

    static MyValues m_values;
};
```

Now make your tests part of the fixture with `TEST_F`. Now `m_values` will be initialized once before all tests in the fixture are ran, all these tests will have access to it, and the cleanup will be done after all tests have finished executing.

For more information, please take a look at https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#sharing-resources-between-tests-in-the-same-test-suite

Comment: Thank you Marko. I ended up using similar pattern for my case.Its just I was hoping it to avoid  static destruction issues.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not possible with value-parameterized tests because these are generated at compile-time using macros and templates.

You can write a loop in your test itself and perform a test for each value. You can use [custom error messages](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#predicate-assertions-for-better-error-messages) or [log additional information](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#logging-additional-information) to make error messages specific for the value. Or perhaps use [SCOPED_TRACE](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#using-assertions-in-sub-routines).